# Migration to log4j2

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to migrate some code from log4j 1.x to 2.x. Some things are easy to replace, but I cannot find the way to replace this:

```
Object obj = event.getMDC("xxx"); //event is org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent type from log4j 1.x.
```

I know about the method with the bridge but for now I want to skip it and try to do it like this.

MDC can be replace with ThreadContext and I see some people using org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent but it doesn't contain the same methods as LoggingEvent (examples):

- `.getRenderMessage()`
- `.getTrowableInformation()`
- `.getMDC();`

Comment: Can you provide more details on what your code is doing? Unless you want to write custom Log4j2 Core components you don't need [`LogEvent`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent.html). You rarely need to write custom components, often Log4j2 Core already has the feature you are looking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.